# U-SQL Query data source

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql, executequery

I would like to write query to remote Azure SQL database.

I followed the [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt763307.aspx#code-snippet-6) via *Query Data Source - Method 1*

I was successful to run the query from tutorial:

```
@results1 =
  SELECT *
  FROM EXTERNAL MyAzureSQLDBDataSource EXECUTE @"SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS serverName, GETDATE() AS dayTime, DB_NAME() AS databaseName";
```

But...

I would like to update this query to following form:

```
DECLARE @queryA string = @"SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS serverName, GETDATE() AS dayTime, DB_NAME() AS databaseName";

@results2 =
  SELECT *
  FROM EXTERNAL MyAzureSQLDBDataSource EXECUTE @queryA;
```

I got an error

> E_CSC_USER_SYNTAXERROR: syntax error. Expected one of: string-literal

Any idea why I cannot use query stored in string value?

In real query I need to dynamically create query based on parameters in where statement.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621291.aspx you can provide only a literal, not a variable:

> EXECUTE csharp_string_literal
>
> The string literal contains a query
> expression in the language supported by the remote data source. E.g.,
> if the data source is an Azure SQL Database, then the query string
> would be T-SQL.

Comment: Is why it not possible to use concatenation of literals? For Example `@results1 =
  SELECT *
  FROM EXTERNAL MyAzureSQLDBDataSource 
  EXECUTE @"SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS serverName, GETDATE() AS dayTime, " + @"DB_NAME() AS databaseName";`